# React Formik Form with styled-components getting entirely re-rendered after typing 1 character

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, styled-components, formik

There's a simple form build using Formik in my project which I used some snippets from their  [official documentation page.](https://formik.org/docs/tutorial) But, for some reason, the entire component reloads without even **formik.values** getting updated.

**The form code:**
*Default HTML Form with useFormik, the "Form" is a styled.div`css` from [styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components)*

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import { useFormik } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import { validate } from 'gerador-validador-cpf';
import InputContainer from '../components/input';
import Button from '../components/button';

import { Form } from './styles'; // styled.form`css` from 'styled-components'

interface FormValues {
  cpf: string; // Brazilian individual taxpayer registry identification
  password: string;
}

const SignUpForm: FC = () => {
  const formik = useFormik<FormValues>({
    initialValues: {
      cpf: '',
      password: '',
    },
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
      }, 400);
    },
    validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
      fullName: Yup.string()
        .min(15, 'Precisamos de seu nome completo')
        .required('É necessário preencher este campo'),
      cpf: Yup.string()
        .required('É necessário preencher este campo')
        .test(
          'cpf-number',
          'Por favor, informe um CPF válido',
          (value) => !!value && validate(value),
        ),
    }),
  });

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
      <InputContainer
        label="CPF"
        onChange={formik.handleChange}
        onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
        value={formik.values.cpf}
      />
      {formik.touched.cpf && formik.errors.cpf && (
        <div className="error">{formik.errors.cpf}</div>
      )}

      <InputContainer
        label="Senha"
        onChange={formik.handleChange}
        onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
        value={formik.values.password}
      />
      {formik.touched.password && formik.errors.password && (
        <div className="error">{formik.errors.password}</div>
      )}

      <Button type="submit">ENTRAR</Button>
      <p>
        <a href="/sign-in">Já possui conta?</a>
      </p>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default SignUpForm;
```

**The "InputContainer" code:**

```js
import React, { FC, InputHTMLAttributes } from 'react';
import { InputContainer } from './styles'; // styled.div`css` from 'styled-components'

interface InputProps extends InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {
  name: string;
  label: string;
}

const InputField: FC<InputProps> = ({ name, label, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <InputContainer>
      <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>
      <input id={name} {...name} type="text" autoComplete="off" {...rest} />
    </InputContainer>
  );
};

export default InputField;
```

I tried a lot of existing solutions over the internet (including Stack), but I keep getting the same issue on the application.
My formik version is 2.2.6. When the Form re-renders, any input loses its focus and all the input values also get lost.

Comment: You are missing the `name` attribute on your two `InputContainer` elements.  Is that the issue, or is it something else?  I can't reproduce the issue with your code but I am familiar with the problem of inputs losing focus.  It happens when the input component is created as a variable inside of another component, such that it gets re-created on every render.

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay. As I'm new to React I make stupid mistakes sometimes. Even with the name attribute in the inputs, the form was being re-rendered. The inputs were really being created as variables. I couldn't solve the problem, so I separated the components. Now it's working! Thanks a lot for the help :)! I still want to know if there is another way though :(

Comment: You can create a render function that you call like `renderInput(props)` instead of a component `<My Input {...props}/>`.  If you want to create components you pretty much have to separate them into top-level components.  You could maybe memoize them using `useMemo` but honestly that is silly and you should separate them.